# CSV overwrite line if same date else append to new line

Tags: php, csv

I want to write `$totalToday` data from API to csv file. If current date not existed, append new record for current date. I've came with following solution.

```
$search      = date("d/m/Y");
$lines       = file('data.csv');
$line_number = false;
foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
 $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE);
}
if(!$line_number){
 $entry = array(date("d/m/Y"), $totalToday);
 $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a');
 fputcsv($fp, $entry);
 fclose($fp); 
}
```

My problem is $totalToday from API get updated time to time. I want to record the latest update. so I replaced `$search = date("d/m/Y");` with `$search = date("d/m/Y"), $totalToday` now I have multiple record for same date in my data.csv. I want to overwrite the current date record with very latest data without append to new line. How to accomplish my requirement

**Example data:** (first rows)

```
    date,newCases,totalToday
    13/04/2020,21,110
    14/04/2020,26,125
    14/04/2020,30,130
```

I want to replace `14/04/2020,26,125` with `14/04/2020,30,130`

Comment: Does the csv only contain a date only in one column? Can you please edit your question and put a few rows how your data.csv looks like?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld  It contains few more columns as well.
Date,NewCases,TotalToday
12/04/2020,10,100
13/04/2020,21,110
14/04/2020,26,125

Comment: So you get for example 14/04/2020,18,100 from an API and you want to replace the 14/04/2020,26,125 with 14/04/2020,18,100 in your csv-file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, Edited question for your ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be this:

```
<?php
$search = '14/04/2020';
$other_data_from_api = array(188,102);

$lines = file('data.csv');

//Create a new array and set all dates as keys
//The latest set key would be the current
$new_arr = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $exp = explode(',', $line);
    $new_arr[$exp[0]] = array($exp[1], $exp[2]);
}

/*
So in your example:
13/04/2020,21,110
14/04/2020,26,125
14/04/2020,30,130

the array $new_arr would contain:
[13/04/2020] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => 110
    )

[14/04/2020] => Array
    (
        [0] => 30
        [1] => 130
    )


*/


//Rewrite the whole file with values from this new array    
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
foreach($new_arr as $key=>$line) {  
    $entry = $key . ',' . implode(',', $line);
    fputs($fp, $entry);
}
fclose($fp);
```

You could also:

```
//Rewrite the whole file with values from this new array  
//And include the actual data from the API
//(Then 188,102 would be included with the data of the $search variable)
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
foreach($new_arr as $key=>$line) {  
    if ($search == $key) { 
        $entry = $search . ',' . implode(',', $other_data_from_api);
    }
    else {
        $entry = $key . ',' . implode(',', $line);
    }
    fputs($fp, $entry);
}
fclose($fp);
```